# Feynman’s QED explanation of reflection from a small mirror

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection, interference, superposition

In the “QED: The strange theory of light and matter” professor Feynman explains at page 45 and following how the simple rule introduced in the first chapter can explain the geometrical law of reflection from a mirror. In particular at figure 25 he considers a short mirror just below a point source S and a photomultiplier P capable to detect single photon events. He states: “there is real reflection happening but is just cancelling out”. My questions are:

1. Feynman’s example discards the contributions of the mirror edges. Therefore the statement “there is real reflection happening but is just cancelling out” is incorrect in general because the photomultiplier will receive photons. Do you agree?
2. is there an experimental way to “exclude” the photons from the edges so to prove the statement “there is real reflection happening but is just cancelling out”?
3. if 2. is YES, can you suggest a paper reporting about such an experiment?

[image: reflection]

Comment: It would be useful to other people if you could add snapshots or images related to your questions so that people can easily understand what you're asking without checking up feynman's lectures themselves.

Comment: I added a picture now. Is it clearer?

Comment: It certainly does enhance the question

Comment: The edges of the mirror would scatter light in all directions. Therefore, there would be photons detected by the photo multiplier, albeit with low probability.

Comment: Thanks @flippiefanus, this is an important observation. Feynman’s example in figure 25 did not consider the edge, therefore is a non-realistic example. If we exclude the edges is the statement “there is real reflection happening but is just cancelling out” a valid one? I suspect is not, because is not possible in an experiment to exclude the edges. I will edit the question again to include your observation.